# Kubernetes multi masters не видит других nodes

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

Настраиваю kubernetes multi masters, который должен иметь 2 мастера.

На кожном запускаю установку с указанием конфига:

kubeadm init --config=config.yaml

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3
kind: ClusterConfiguration
etcd:
  endpoints:
  - https://172.16.100.33:2379
  - https://172.16.100.34:2379
  caFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.pem
  certFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/client.pem
  keyFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/client-key.pem
networking:
  podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16
```

Результат проходит успешно. Сертификаты все с одного сервера перекидываю на другой и запускаю аналогичную команду.

Но оба мастера не видят друг друга:

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master4.nullgr.com   Ready    master   15m   v1.12.1

kubectl get node
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master3.nullgr.com   Ready    master   27m   v1.12.1
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

вот рабочий пример инит конфига для 3-х мастерого кластера . etcd на мастерах.
для каждой ноды в конфиге нужно поменять advertiseAddress и nodeName

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: MasterConfiguration
api:
  advertiseAddress: 10.0.2.251
etcd:
  endpoints:
  - "http://10.0.2.250:2379"
  - "http://10.0.2.251:2379"
  - "http://10.0.2.252:2379"
apiServerExtraArgs:
  storage-backend: etcd3
  service-node-port-range: "80-32767"
networking:
  podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16
nodeName: kuberm2
kubernetesVersion: v1.10.0
apiServerCertSANs:
- "10.0.2.250"
- "10.0.2.251"
- "10.0.2.252"
- "127.0.0.1"
- "kub.api.damain.ru"
token: "9o9333333333q7uib"
tokenTTL: "0"
```